# Join a few tables and then group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm using LINQPad to accomplish following:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
q.Id as 'Question id', c.Id as 'Choice Id', c.Content as 'Choice Content', count(*) as 'Answer count'
FROM Answers a
join Choices c on
a.ChoiceId = c.id
join Questions q
on c.QuestionId = q.Id
group by  q.Id, c.Id, c.Content
```

I have this so far but cannot figure out how to group, especially if multiple tables are joined:

```
(
from a in Answers
join c in Choices 
    on a.ChoiceId equals c.Id
join q in Questions 
    on c.QuestionId equals q.Id

select new { q.Id, c.QuestionId,  c.Content}
)
```

Comment: you just need use [`group clause`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) like `group a by new {qid = q.Id, cid=c.Id, c.Content} into g`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Side note: don't `join`, use navigation properties like `Answer.Choices`.